# Magento 2: Change Price on Category View Only

Tags: php, plugins, magento2

Is it possible to only change the price of products on the category page and not on the product page.

I tried the following but this changes the global product price and I only want to change it on the category page.

di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_product" type=" Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product " sortOrder="1" disabled="true"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Plugin/Product.php:

```
class Product
{
    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        return $result + 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you use XML layouts:
Create a file in: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/**catalog_category_view.xml**.

And in this file you must point to your custom block class. At the moment a can't give more details, but it is tha way.